# How to add column to a dataframe from a list preserving the order of the list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, csv

I have a list A= ['APPLE', 'Orange','Mango']

I have a data frame that is like this

```
APPLE APPLE Orange Orange Mango Mango

x.     y.      x.     y.    x.    y.  

1      2       3      3      4     2
:      :       :      :      :     :
```

I want to change it add another column called fruit after every second row such that the data frame looks like this:

```
APPLE APPLE Fruit  Orange Orange Fruit Mango Mango. Fruit

x.     y.    APPLE   x.     y.   Orange x.    y.  Mango

1      2    APPLE    3      3   Orange    4     2   Mango
:      :    APPLE    :      :      :     :          Mango
```

Comment: @MartinGustafsson well I have a dataframe with same column name for different columns

Comment: @MartinGustafsson that is not true, but it depends on how the column is created. For example, you could do this without error: `df.columns = ['APPLE', 'APPLE', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Mango', 'Mango']`. You will run into issues when renaming columns using a dictionary method, so again it depends on how it is done.

Comment: @DavidErickson thank you for confirming.Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @DavidErickson Thanks for explaining, just learned that.

Comment: @DavidErickson Again, do you know how to get the particular data frame?

Comment: @amarykya_ishtmella does tone of the solutions solve?

Comment: @DavidErickson thank you so much for the solution.I used stack/unstack and then used the columns to get the new dataframe.

Comment: Thanks @amarykya_ishtmella Was there an issue with my solution? I think it is more dynamic than the one that you accepted.

Comment: @DavidErickson no, both worked well. I wish I could accept both, here I just took the one I got first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is far from the best solution, but it works.

```
import pandas as pd

def add_fruit(df, fruits):
  new_df = pd.DataFrame()
  for fruit in fruits:
    df_copy = df[fruit].copy()
    df_copy["Fruit"] = [fruit] * len(df.index)
    if new_df.empty:
      new_df = df_copy
    else:
      new_df = pd.concat([new_df, df_copy], axis=1, join='inner')
  return new_df

fruits = ['APPLE', 'Orange','Mango']

df = pd.DataFrame([['x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y'], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2], [7,8,9,10,11,12]], columns = ['APPLE','APPLE','Orange','Orange','Mango','Mango'])

print(add_fruit(df, fruits))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this dynamically regardless of number of fruit or number of columns per fruit. Just create a series that will return the column index at which location we should `.insert` the column as well as the the name of the fruit.

1. You have to find the number of identical column names with `value_counts()`, then `[df.columns.unique()]` is there so you can maintain order (otherwise `value_counts` will sort and this will add the columns in incorrect places).
2. Then, add 1, because you are inserting a column after each duplicated fruit name (which increase the number of columns by 1 per group).
3. Next, take the cumulative sum and subtract 1, which gives you the position you need to add the columns.
4. Finally, loop through `srs` (the position you are adding columns in with `insert`) and also loop through `fruit` simultaneously with `zip`:

This is what `srs` looks like and is what you are looping through to dynamically add columns:

```
APPLE     2
Orange    5
Mango     8
```

--

```
# df.columns = ['APPLE', 'APPLE', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Mango', 'Mango']
srs = (df.columns.value_counts()[df.columns.unique()] + 1).cumsum() - 1
fruit = srs.index
for f, i in zip(fruit, srs):
    df.insert(i,f'Fruit{i}',f)
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('\d+','')
df
Out[1]: 
  APPLE APPLE  Fruit Orange Orange   Fruit Mango Mango  Fruit
0    x.    y.  APPLE     x.     y.  Orange    x.    y.  Mango
1     1     2  APPLE      3      3  Orange     4     2  Mango
2     :     :  APPLE      :      :  Orange     :     :  Mango
```